# Why won’t my Macbook Pro identify it’s own battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Update: I’ve decided I’m giving up on what I have to work with, and I’m gonna buy a new battery.

I have a 13 inch MacBook Pro that I have been working on refurbishing, and I’ve run into an issue where if I unplug it from the charger it shuts down and it won’t show battery percentage. I think this might have something to do with when I was dusting out the insides of the computer and a misaligned flex cable, but I am really not sure. Here’s an image of white happens when I first turn on the computer: [image]

i’m really at a loss as to what to do at this point, because I’ve just been scouring forums for the better part of a month.

Comment: What does the Power section of System Information say?

Comment: What year of MBP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either the battery is not connected or it has failed.

Did you receive any messages about “service battery”?

You will likely be taking the cover off again to check.

Comment: I don’t believe I’d received any such message, though the battery not working would make a lot of sense. I’ll have to test that theory tonight

Comment: It might be interesting to run the Console app for a while and see what messages are appearing there

Answer (score 1):

I have just replaced a battery in a 2016 MacBook Pro 13 with a third party replacement. It was the last part of a fairly major exercise to replace the keyboard. When I turned the laptop on it worked while plugged in but failed as soon as I removed the power cable. Turns out I had failed to transfer a cable from the old battery I had removed to the new replacement. Once I had put the cable in it started working although I am seeing some concerning entries in dmesg which I suspect is related to the third party battery not having the same hardware as the genuine part (update: actually was due to a faulty third party battery):

```
Failed to read nominal voltage rating key . voltage:0 rc:0x84
```

The cable is the one in the picture below from [ifixit battery replacement guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Function+Keys+Late+2016+Battery+Replacement/88305). I would check that it is connected correctly at both ends - something you will need to do regardless even if you are only replacing the battery.

[image]